# Tracking object allocation in python

Tags: python, allocation, creation

Is there any method I can override that will allow me to use print statements / pdb / etc. to keep track of every time an instance of my class is allocated? While unpickling some objects I am seeming to get some that never have either `__setstate__` or `__init__` called on them. I tried overriding `__new__` and printing out the id of every object I make in `__new__`, but I am still encountering objects with ids that were never printed.

Edit: here is my code I use for altering (instrumenting) `__new__` of my class and all of its super-classes except for `object` itself:

```
class Allocator:
    def __init__(self, my_class):
       self.my_class = my_class
       self.old_new = my_class.__new__

    def new(self, * args, ** kargs):
        rval = self.old_new(*args, ** kargs)
        #rval = super(self.my_class,cls).__new__(cls)
        print 'Made '+str(self.my_class)+' with id '+str(id(rval))
        return rval

def replace_allocator(cls):
    if cls == object:
        return

    setattr(cls,'__new__',Allocator(cls).new)
    print cls.__base__

    try:
        for parent in cls.__base__:
            replace_allocator(parent)
   except:
        replace_allocator(cls.__base__)
```

I call replace_allocator on my classes' parent class as soon as it is imported in the main script. My class has a custom `__new__` to begin with, which also prints out the id.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain they are different instances? Have you checked if `id(instance)` matches?

Comment: Are you trying to use `Allocator(cls)` as a type cast? If so, it is wrong, because in Python it is a constructor call for an `Allocator` object, and the `.new` part will get a new bound-method instance.

Comment: Rosh: Yes. My allocator function shows the way that I print out id(instance). Later, when I find an object that is missing some fields that should have been added by setstate or init, I print out its id too. If I grep for that id in the earlier printouts there are no hits.

Comment: Apalala: It is indeed my intention to use `Allocator(cls)` as a constructor call for an `Allocator` object. The point of an `Allocator` constructed with `cls` is to call the original `__new__` method of `cls` and report the `id` of the resulting object instance.

Comment: The iteration should be `for parent in cls.__bases__`.  You don't need the fall-back to `cls.__base__`. And don't use catch-all `except:` clauses. They always bite you.

Comment: Beware that if the class doesn't define `__new__`, `cls.__new__` will be the constructor of its first base. Weird side-effects are to be expected when you replace `__new__` like that. Take it out of `cls.__dict__` instead. You can also simply walk over `cls.mro()` instead of walking the bases yourself.

Comment: @Rosh:  If a class -- say `A` -- does not define `__new__()`, then calling `A()` will call `A.__new__()` anyway, and the definition of `__new__()` will be taken from some base class.  The code above does exactly the same -- it calls `A.__new__()`.  There are no weird side effects to be expected.

Answer (score 5):

(This is more of a comment than an answer.)

Quoting Guido's [Unifying types and classes in Python 2.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#__new__):

> There are situations where a new instance is created without calling `__init__` (for example when the instance is loaded from a pickle). There is no way to create a new instance without calling `__new__` (although in some cases you can get away with calling a base class's `__new__`).

If you are using new-style classes (descendants of `object`), `__new__()` should always be called.  I don't think the obscure cases "you can get away with calling a base class's `__new__`" in will happen accidently, though I don't know what these cases actually are.

And just to add an example:

```
In [1]: class A(object):
   ...:     def __new__(cls):    
   ...:         print "A"
   ...:         return object.__new__(cls)
   ...:     

In [2]: A()
A
Out[2]: <__main__.A object at 0xa3a95cc>

In [4]: object.__new__(A)
Out[4]: <__main__.A object at 0xa3a974c>
```

Comment: This sounds like a feasible approach but unfortunately if you can get away with calling the base class, then that might explain why there are objects getting allocated without my knowledge. I'm only allowed to override `__new__` for classes other than `object` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using new-style classes? For Pickle to call `__setstate__`, the `__getstate__` method should also be defined on the class [returning a non-False value](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__).

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to detect objects as they are created. But yes I am using new-style classes and I do have a `__getstate__` implemented. Also, `__setstate__` is getting called on most but not all instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help you, but Python's garbage collector has [introspective capabilities](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html) that might be worth taking a look at.

Comment: The question is about keeping track of the *creation* of objects.

Comment: You're right, I most probably misunderstood the question. But now I wonder, won't the garbage collector need itself to monitor object allocation? If so, one might devise a method to hook into the gc and figure out when an object of interested gets allocated. I'm not questioning what you said, I'm just curious.